# Changing values in a column in a Pandas dataFrame by using another dataFramen and two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataFrames:

The first dataframe df contains the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['US0378331005', 'CH0038863350', 'DE0007164600'],
            'Country': ['United States', 'Switzerland', 'Germany'], 'ETF': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
```

The second dataframe Lookup_Category is a lookup table to link the column 'Country'  in df to column 'Country'  in Lookup_Category and to link columns 'ETF' to each other:

```
Lookup_Category = pd.DataFrame({'ETF': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
            'Country': ['United States', 'Switzerland', 'Belgium'],
            'Category': ['cat1','cat2', 'cat3']})
```

The result of the new dataframe shall be:

[image]

Hot to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can merge on two columns:

```py
x = pd.merge(df, Lookup_Category, on=["Country", "ETF"], how="left").fillna("")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
           ISIN        Country ETF Category
0  US0378331005  United States   A     cat1
1  CH0038863350    Switzerland   B     cat2
2  DE0007164600        Germany   C
```

Comment: Thank you  very much. What if the original version of the dataframe Lookup_Category consists of much more columns than in this example? What to do if only the column 'Category' should be added to df?

Comment: @Numpy You can filter the columns afterwards. For example `x = x[['ISIN', 'Country', 'ETF', 'Category']]` (add/remove more columns as you wish)

Comment: Ty Andrej, that's exactly what I did and works pretty fine. But I love to see a solution where I dont need to remove columns afterwards.